# Как вывести изображение с экрана разбитого телефона

Tags: android

Тут такое дело, упал телефон. Необходимо управлять экраном телефона через USB. Какие программы под Windows вы посоветуете чтобы на телефоне не пришлось выполнять действия? а понадобился для отладки Android приложений.

Comment: какая модель телефона?

Comment: Попробуйте Vysor